# Python reading met.no weather API gives "string indices must be integers" when trying to convert to JSON

Tags: python

I am reading met.no weather API from the URL https://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/2.0/complete?lat=59.911491&lon=10.757933

```
import json
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

# Read forecast
url = "https://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/2.0/complete?lat=59.911491&lon=10.757933"
req = Request(url)
req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:101.0) Python/3.10.5')
content: bytes = urlopen(req).read()

# Convert to JSON
json_str: str = content.decode('utf8').replace("'", '"')
json_data = json.load(json_str)

# Print data
type = json_data["type"]
print(f"{type}")
```

This gives me error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'load'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a little typo mistake. You should use `json.loads` instead of `json.load`.

```py
import json
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

# Read forecast
url = "https://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/2.0/complete?lat=59.911491&lon=10.757933"
req = Request(url)
req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:101.0) Python/3.10.5')
content: bytes = urlopen(req).read()

# Convert to JSON
json_str: str = content.decode('utf8').replace("'", '"')
json_data = json.loads(json_str)

# Print data
type = json_data["type"]
print(f"{type}")
```

**Output:**

```
Feature
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `json.load` expects an IO stream as argument, but you are giving a string. Try the method `json.loads`

Check the documentation of json library [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)